Boy comes back from the dead to date girl
It's an old movie maybe 80's or so. I can only remember these parts:
Scene: In this movie I remember a scene where this dude likes a chick, I think this part is inside a store, and there's a thief who enters with a gun and robs it. The thief fires the gun at the chick but the dude jumps and saves her life, he dies...
Scene: This is the part where the dead dude get's buried in some cemetery. The chick says a wish before throwing a rose into the casket below. Her wish is "I wish I could see you one more time..." or something like that.
Scene: The dead dude rises from the dead only for a day (looking like a zombie), he later meets with the scared chick and they date I think and spend time together etc...
Scene: If i remember correctly, the dude time's is over and has to return to rest, to the cemetery. I can't remember anything else.
Please help me identify this movie, I want to see it again! 

Sounds like the romantic zombie comedy My Boyfriend's Back from 1993. From IMDb:

Johnny is a teenager like everyone else. He's in love with a beautiful girl named Missy, but he can't tell it to her. One day the shop where Missy works gets robbed and Johnny is killed trying to help. But Johnny doesn't want to stay dead, so he returns to his life like nothing ever happened. After a while he discovers that his body is disintegrating and he must feed with human flesh if he wants to survive. Looks like he is a real zombie... 

Missy tosses a rose on his coffin and wishes they'd gotten to know each other. Later, Johnny rises from the grave, still clutching the rose. Here's a scene from the movie:




You are right this is the movie now I remember, the ending was a surprise too. Thanx Walt.
